# What is %z useful for in GNU date?

Tags: date, gnu, timezone, coreutils

I'm in the UK running these 2 commands (using `gdate` as I'm on a Mac with `date (GNU coreutils) 8.32` installed):

```
# A UK winter date, timezone in UK at this time is GMT = UTC
$ gdate '--date=TZ="Australia/Sydney" 2021-02-11T03:02' +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z"
2021-02-10 16:02:00 +0000

# A UK summer date, timezone in the UK at this time is UTC+1
$ gdate '--date=TZ="Australia/Sydney" 2020-08-11T03:02' +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z"
2020-08-10 18:02:00 +0100
```

I expected `%z` to return the offset from UTC of the Sydney time, which would be something like `+1200` or `+1100`. I'm only guessing at those, I was hoping `gdate` would tell me! But instead it's returning `+0000` and `+0100`, which look suspiciously like my system's UTC offsets at those times.

`man gdate` has the following:

```
%z     +hhmm numeric time zone (e.g., -0400)
```

Which suggests that it should be doing what I expect, not what it's doing. Can anyone shed any light on this? Does GNU date use my system timezone for anything?

---

On @steeldriver's suggestion:

```
$ TZ=Australia/Sydney gdate '--date=2020-08-11T03:02' +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z"
2020-08-11 03:02:00 +1000
```

This (I think!) gives me what I wanted.

Comment: I'm not sure that adding the timezone as part of the date string works in the way you think it does - did you try setting the TZ variable in the command's environment ex. `TZ="Australia/Sydney" gdate '--date=2020-08-11T03:02' +"%Y-%m-%d %T %z"` instead?

Comment: Thanks! That seems to have done the trick, would you mind explaining how/why in an answer?

Comment: TBH I'm not sure how to explain the difference - let's wait and see if a more knowledgeable contributor posts an answer

Comment: It seems you calculated the UK time when it was 3:02 AM in Sydney. Related: [“What time is it in New York when a Paris clock shows 6:30am on October 31, 2004?”](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/Specifying-time-zone-rules.html)

Comment: This is the shell setting the env var for the command. See https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Simple-Command-Expansion

Comment: @glennjackman Not exactly. The source input string may contain its own time zone explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

The date command is quite simple (on first look). But could become more complex once you look a bit deeper under its structure of values.

The simplest date command requires a "point in time" input and prints "a point in time" value (with additional changes guided by the format requested). If we rely on the default output format, we could do:

```
$ from='2020-08-11T03:02'

$ date -d "$from"

Tue 11 Aug 2020 03:02:00 AM EDT
```

That is assuming that the local set in the computer is in `New_York`.
And that date would use the default TZ as set for both input and output.

Or, explicitly:

```
TZ="America/New_York" date -d "$from"
Tue 11 Aug 2020 03:02:00 AM EDT
```

That is the same date as the input `from='2020-08-11T03:02'` because date apply the set TZ to both input and output if there isn't additional information.

But the input string could be (also) written as:

`from='2020-08-11T07:02 +0000'       # Please note the 7 (instead of 3).`

The same point in time as would be given by an user looking at time as it is in UTC.

```
$ TZ="America/New_York" date -d "$from"
Tue 11 Aug 2020 03:02:00 AM EDT
```

And the same command gives the same time value in New York as before, but the input value was different. It could have been to local time of someone in India:

```
$ from='2020-08-11T12:32+0530'

$ TZ="America/New_York" date -d "$from"

Tue 11 Aug 2020 03:02:00 AM EDT
```

Which results in the same value and "point in time" at New York.

To get the **local** string used above you do need the `%z` format:

```
from='2020-08-11T12:32+0530';TZ="Asia/Kolkata" date -d "$from"
Tue 11 Aug 2020 12:32:00 PM IST

from='2020-08-11T12:32+0530';TZ="Asia/Kolkata" date -d "$from" +'%c %z'
Tue 11 Aug 2020 12:32:00 PM IST +0530
```

Which is still the same "point in time" in New York:

```
from='2020-08-11T12:32+0530';TZ="America/New_York" date -d "$from" +'%c %z'
Tue 11 Aug 2020 03:02:00 AM EDT -0400
```

That is one use of the `%z` format.

The point is: **a time string is not unique unless it also contains the value of the "time zone" used to generate such time string.**

## Olson database

I used numerical values above for the time zone: from='2020-08-11T12:32+0530'

But It is also possible (and recommendable) to use **Olson database** values:

```
from='TZ="Asia/Kolkata" 2020-08-11T12:32'; 

TZ="America/New_York" date -d "$from" +'%c %z'

Tue 11 Aug 2020 03:02:00 AM EDT -0400
```

The Olsen database values doesn't change with "summer time". It doesn't change from EST to EDT in "New York" at some (probably unknown to users from other countries) year date. It is stable.

```
TZ="America/New_York" date -d 'TZ="America/New_York" 01/01/20 03:30'
Wed 01 Jan 2020 03:30:00 AM EST

TZ="America/New_York" date -d 'TZ="America/New_York" 07/01/20 03:30'
Wed 01 Jul 2020 03:30:00 AM EDT
```

Using that concept, transformations of local time strings are possible (and easy) for cities either in the north or the south:

```
$ ddate(){ TZ="$toTZ" date -d 'TZ="'"$fromTZ"'" '"$1" +'%c %z'; }

$ toTZ='America/New_York'
$ fromTZ='Africa/Johannesburg'    # Which is in the south but has no DST.

$ ddate '1/1/20';ddate '4/1/20'; ddate '7/1/20'

Tue 31 Dec 2019 05:00:00 PM EST -0500
Tue 31 Mar 2020 06:00:00 PM EDT -0400
Tue 30 Jun 2020 06:00:00 PM EDT -0400 


$ fromTZ='Pacific/Auckland'                   # Which has a DST set.

$ ddate '1/1/20';ddate '4/1/20'; ddate '7/1/20'

Tue 31 Dec 2019 06:00:00 AM EST -0500
Tue 31 Mar 2020 07:00:00 AM EDT -0400
Tue 30 Jun 2020 08:00:00 AM EDT -0400

Note the three **different** times 6, 7 and 8.
```